# How can you redirect a script's output through a process?

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

I want to redirect a bash script's output through a logging program. Specifically, Apache's logrotate utility. The redirection needs to be set within the script itself.

If the redirection were done on the command line, while executing the script, it would look like this:

```
myscript | logrotate -l $LOGFILE.%F 86400 2>&1
```

Here is some pseudo-code that goes inside the script to accomplish the output redirection, which does not work:

```
exec >(logrotate -l $LOGFILE.log.%F 86400) 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using a named pipe.

```
PIPE=/var/run/myscript/pipe
mkfifo "$PIPE"
logrotate -l "$LOGFILE.%F" 86400 < "$PIPE" &
exec > "$PIPE"
```

Also, regarding your 2>&1 redirection -- make sure you understand to what it is applied. In your first example it's applied to logrotate, while in the second "example" it would be applied to your script.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you want:

```
exec  >  >(logrotate -l $LOGFILE.log.%F 86400)
```

Please see "process substitution" in Bash manual.

Please note that process substitution is not standard. The fallback is named pipes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a script *can* redirect it's own output.  Can you perhaps write a wrapper script for it though?

myscript:

```
myscript.real "$@" | logrotate -l $LOGFILE.%F 86400 2>&1
```

Comment: Use `"$@"` instead of `$*` to pass positional parameters to get proper quoting.

Comment: Nope, it should be in double-quotes -- exactly as I wrote. `$@` without quotes is indeed no different from `$*` without quotes.

Comment: A script or a { } block *can* redirect its own output using `exec >somefile`. But Joshua's question is harder.

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to do this - in Bourne shell from Unix 7th Edition onwards - is:

```
{
...body of script here...
} | logrotate ...
```

If you want to redirect the errors too, then:

```
{
...body of script here...
} 2>&1 | logrotate ...
```

The only downside to this notation is the (often rather wide) separation between the start of the redirection and the end of it.  From that point of view, the Bash process substitution is probably better if you're sure you'll have Bash available on all the relevant systems.